# React.js useState() add/update/delete

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am trying to learn to react.js with hooks. I have encountered an issue with an array of objects.
Here's the code

```
const [stories, setStoreis] = useState(
[
    {
      name: "1st Story",
      sid: "1",
      appartmentDetails: [
        {
          aptName: "Master Bath",
          status: "",
          media: Logo,
        },
        {
          aptName: "Master Bath",
          status: "",
          media: Logo,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "2nd Story",
      sid: "2",
      appartmentDetails: [
        {
          aptName: "Master Bath",
          status: "",
          media: Logo,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
);
```

To add new Story here's what I am doing

```
const newStory = {
      name: "3rd Story",
      sid: "3",
      appartmentDetails: [],
    };
setStory([...stories, newStory]);
```

It's adding completely fine. Now I want to add appartmentDetails. **How** can I add appartmentDetails of specific story? Also if I want to update how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with nested data like this with immutability in mind, I'd suggest using [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) as it makes cases like this *much* easier. There's a [`use-immer`](https://github.com/immerjs/use-immer) hook that is very useful to this.

Edit: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-immer-add-update-delete-6dqpr?file=/src/App.js) with an example of use-immer with create/update/delete on the story data.

```
import { useImmer } from 'use-immer';


const [stories, updateStories] = useImmer(
[
    {
      name: "1st Story",
      sid: "1",
      appartmentDetails: [
        {
          aptName: "Master Bath",
          status: "",
          media: Logo,
        },
        {
          aptName: "Master Bath",
          status: "",
          media: Logo,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "2nd Story",
      sid: "2",
      appartmentDetails: [
        {
          aptName: "Master Bath",
          status: "",
          media: Logo,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
);
```

Your add story code can remain exactly the same:

```
const newStory = {
      name: "3rd Story",
      sid: "3",
      apartmentDetails: [],
    };
updateStories([...stories, newStory]);
```

Pushing to apartmentDetails:

```
updateStories(draft=>{draft[index].apartmentDetails.push({aptName: 'New Apartment'})});
```

Updating apartmentDetails:

```
updateStories(draft=>{
  const story = draft.find(story=>story.sid === '2');
  story.apartmentDetails[0].aptName = 'Better Bath'
});
```

If you don't want an external library it's much more complicated to work with:

```
setStories(stories=>stories.map((story,index)=>index===changeIndex? {...story, apartmentDetails: story.apartmentDetails.concat([{aptName: 'New Apartment'}])} :story));
```

Comment: If I am adding apartmentDetails its not updating any thing

Comment: also what is the index here in ```draft[index]```

Comment: @HamzaAfzal, I added a codesandbox with a working example of update/delete/create using use-immer. I also changed the `draft[index]` line since it was unclear. `index` was meant to be some arbitrary index of the relevant story. So I changed it to use `Array#find` and the `sid` value. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a specific story using `Array.find`:

```
const story = stories.find(story => story.sid === '3');
const storyWithDetails = {...story, appartmentDetails: [{aptName: "Master Bath"}]};
```

To manipulate existing `appartmentDetails` array you can use array methods like:

```
const storyWithDetails = {...story, appartmentDetails: story.appartmentDetails.filter()]};

const storyWithDetails = {...story, appartmentDetails: story.appartmentDetails.map()]};

const storyWithDetails = {...story, appartmentDetails: story.appartmentDetails.slice()]}
```

... and so on. Then put it back into state like:

```
const otherStoris = stories.filter(story => story.sid !== '3');
setStory([...otherStoris, storyWithDetails]);
```

Comment: Thanks T J. Now what if ```appartmentDetails``` is an array of object. how to set items there?

Comment: When adding an apartment in the story it changes the position. how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

@Zachary Haber, i am adding changeIndex and its saying; "cant find variable changeIndex"